# UIScrollView disable vertical bounce only at bottom

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've been searching for a way to disable vertical bounce for a UIScrollView but only at bottom. I still need to have the bounce at the top.

Couldn't find anything. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [Disable UIScrollView bounce at the top of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736245/disable-uiscrollview-bounce-at-the-top-of-the-screen), by changing the scroll view's `bounces` propery in `scrollViewDidScroll` depending on its scroll position.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewDidScroll` to check the content offset of the scrollview and more or less check if the user is trying to scroll beyond the bottom bounds of the scroll view. Then just use this to set the scroll back to the end of the scroll view. It happens so rapidly that you can't even tell that the scroll view bounced or extended beyond its bounds at all.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Comment: What about doing the opposite ? bottom bounce ?

Comment: is this good ?
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
    }

Comment: You might want to take the contentInset into account too: correct for scrollView.contentInset.bottom.

Answer (score 14):

To disable vertical bounce at the top in Swift:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }
}
```

To disable vertical bounce at the bottom in Swift:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height
    }
}
```

Comment: @Blacky That would disable the bounce for the top and bottom, question asks for only one

Comment: If you do not have it set up already, just a friendly reminder to add UIScrollViewDelegate and scrollView.delegate = self

Answer (score 4):

Based on 0x7fffffff's answer I've created a class:

VerticalBounceControl.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VerticalBounceControl : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bounce;

- (id) initWithScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView bounceAtTop:(BOOL)bounceAtTop bounceAtBottom:(BOOL)bounceAtBottom;

@end
```

VerticalBounceControl.m

```
#import "VerticalBounceControl.h"

@interface VerticalBounceControl ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bounceAtTop;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bounceAtBottom;
@end

@implementation VerticalBounceControl

- (id) initWithScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView bounceAtTop:(BOOL)bounceAtTop bounceAtBottom:(BOOL)bounceAtBottom {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.bounce = YES;
        self.scrollView = scrollView;
        self.bounceAtTop = bounceAtTop;
        self.bounceAtBottom = bounceAtBottom;
        [self.scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [self.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
    self.scrollView = nil;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {
        if (self.bounce && ((self.scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0 && self.bounceAtTop) || (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y>=self.scrollView.contentSize.height-1 && self.bounceAtBottom))) {
            self.scrollView.bounces = YES;
        } else {
            self.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

that can be used without the caller being a delegate of `UIScrollView` like this:

```
VerticalBounceControl* bounceControl = [[VerticalBounceControl alloc] initWithScrollView:anyScrollView bounceAtTop:YES bounceAtBottom:NO];
```

This way you can have this bounce behavior for `UIScrollView`s that you don't want to alter their delegate (like `UIWebView`'s one).

Again, thanks go @0x7fffffff for the solution!

Comment: A category of `UIScrollView` would have been a more elegant solution

Comment: @MarkE What would a swift implementation involve? If not without the overriding of delegate methods. Curious.

Comment: @Pavan I'm not very familiar with swift, I've not been on ios dev for a while. Although my comment was not swift related, categories are just a way to extend classes which I can't tell if is available on swift

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3:**

This works to disable vertical bounce only at the bottom:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.height
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jordi It works but is there any way to sop left-right too? I only need top bonce.

Answer (score 1):

Let's disable the `bounces` when scroll to the bottom.

```swift
scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.height
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `fabsf()` to 0x7fffffff♦'s solution to also cater for negative(downward) scroll:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (fabsf(scrollView.contentOffset.y) >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking a solution to disable bottom bounce only for a scrollview with wider contentSize width than device since I am using paging. None of those work for me but I found a way to do it. I thought I should share this since I wasted two days just to do this.
I am using Swift 4 but this applies to objective c if you know how to convert this which should be easy if you have experience with both.

This works in a scrollview with device screen frame as frame.

1. Add variable to be aware for scrollview's current page.
   `var currentPage : Int!`
2. Set initial value
   `currentPage = 0`
3. Update `currentPage` after scrolling
   `public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   let width = scrollView.frame.size.width
   let page = (scrollView.contentOffset.x + (0.5 * width)) / width
   currentPage = Int(page)
   }`
4. Filter bottom scrolling and update contentOffset
   `public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   if CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth < scrollView.contentOffset.x || CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth < scrollView.contentOffset.y || (((CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth - scrollView.contentOffset.x) >= 0) && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0){
           scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
       }
   }`

`CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth < scrollView.contentOffset.x || CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth < scrollView.contentOffset.y` will filter bottom left and right scrolling

`(((CGFloat(currentPage) * screenWidth - scrollView.contentOffset.x) >= 0) && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0)` will filter bottom mid scrolling

`scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0` will stop it from scrolling