# Disable UIScrollView bounce at the top of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have UIScrollView in my app with vertical bounce enabled. I need the bounce at the bottom of the screen but not enabled at the top of the screen.

I no how to detect scrollview with the following:

```
  (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

  // no bounce if scrollView has reached the top of the screen ??
  }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try setting the `bounces` property as the scroll view scrolls, based on the content offset:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100);
}
```

Comment: I would like to understand where does that value `100` coming from? Why is it exactly 100? Do you have an explanation for this @Wain?

Comment: @BrunoBieri It's an arbitrarily chosen value from user testing to get the right feel and prevent false positives. The size of the views mean that decimal places aren't required for the level of accuracy achievable. Many values will likely work based on the size of the scroll view and content...

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you. It wasn't clear to me from the original answer. This means to me that the containing view needs to have at least a height of 100 in order for this code to work.

Answer (score 4):

**SWIFT**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //disable bounce only at the top of the screen
    scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be correct to fulfill the condition before scrolling occurs

```
override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   tableView.bounces = tableView.contentOffset.y > 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pulling only use:

```swift
extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = min(-88, scrollView.contentOffset.y) // -88 or other point
    }
}
```