# UIScrollView disable top bounce

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a ViewController that contains an UIScrollView and I'm trying to disable the bounce effect only on the top of the view.

I tried to add [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736245/disable-uiscrollview-bounce-at-the-top-of-the-screen) in my ViewController class, which is saying to do this :

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //disable bounce only at the top of the screen
    scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100
}
```

But I don't really understand what to do with this. I also tried to implement the UIScrollViewDelegate.

Nothing I tried worked.

[Here is my StoryBoard and ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv3o8.png)

What do I need to do in order to make it works ?

My setup :

- Swift version : 5.1.3
- Xcode version : 11.3.1
- Target iOS version : 13.2
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 (19C57)

Comment: did you set scrollview.delegate = self in your viewController ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect scrollView outlet and then try adding `scrollView.delegate = self` or add `scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100` in your `viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: I tried adding `scrollView.delegate = self` and making my viewcontroller inherit of UIScrollViewDelegate but it don't works

Comment: Adding `scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100` in the `viewDidLoad()` function just disable both top and bottom bounces.

Comment: Add scrollview outlet  just like you did with `imageView` and call it `scrollView`. And then add `scrollView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad()` and then check if your `scrollViewDidScroll()` is called.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable bounces of the `scrollview` then you can take outlet of your `scrollview` and can set bounces property to false in `viewdidload` like below,

```
yourScrollView.bounces = false
```

or you can uncheck bounces from the storyboard also!

Comment: Won't this remove bounces both from top and bottom? He only wants to remove top bounce

Comment: Oh! Okay. I misunderstood the question! Then @ValentinaKonatar's answer is right to disable only top bounce!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
          scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
      }
  }
```

Comment: I tried but the function is never called. What do I need to do ? I tried the answer of @ValentinaKonatar by setting the delegate but don't works.

Comment: take scrollview outlet and add delegate like this scrollView.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

**Okay here is the answer to my problem :**

- In the viewController, add the ScrollView outlet
- In the `viewDidLoad()` function, add this `myScrollView.delegate = self`
- Make your viewController implement UIScrollViewDelegate : `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate { ...`
- Then add the following function :

  func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      myScrollView.bounces = myScrollView.contentOffset.y > 100
  }

Answer (score 0):

Go to Attributes Inspector.
uncheck "Bounce On Scrolll"