# Disable bottom bounce in UITableView with UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I want to disable UITableView bottom bounce, I can't use standard "bounce" property in storyboard, bcs UIRefreshControl needs top bounce for work. So I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084657/uiscrollview-disable-vertical-bounce-only-at-bottom):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

}

It works fine if content height bigger then size of screen, but crashes in other case:
[image]

As u see on picture above UIRefreshControl is not hidden (and there are only 3 cells in uitableview with blank space on bottom if UIRefreshControll is hidden). I have tried to resolve this problem by adding UIRefreshControl height to my method but it didn't help either:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height - self.refreshControl!.frame.size.height {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height + self.refreshControl!.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }
}
```

I am having blank space at top and RefreshControl stops working:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thx.

P.S. My viewDidLoad method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Обновление")
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false;
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    // menu button
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment I found pretty dumb solution:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentSize.height > self.view.frame.size.height && scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }
}
```

I disable bounce only if `contentSize.height > self.view.frame.size.height` , hope some1 knew how to do it better.