# How to Stop UIWebView from “bouncing” vertically scrolling bottom?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

My question is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically), but has one difference. When I scroll to top refresh my website, I want stop bouncing only to the end of the bottom scroll. How do I do this?

Comment: You should be able to set `contentOffset` in scrollview's `scrollviewdidscroll`

Comment: How? Can you explain me with a little code?

Comment: @Pyro sorry, my browser very slow, I want click to vote up, browser crashed and I clicked many times)) Accepted you answer again. Thanks for answer, you solution helped me :) Have a good day.

Comment: Please have a search yourself first after being given suggestions, instead of immediately ask for code when you ask a question in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webview.scrollView.delegate = self

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
    }   
}
```

Set the delegate of your webview and set the content offset of the webview's scrollview

Ref taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14084747/4557505

Comment: finally I came across an answer that fixes it permanently, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Personally in Xcode 7.3 in Swift, I Simply add this in the viewDidLoad Function:

```
UIWebview.scrollView.bounces = false;
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent command in obj-c? I'm using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) and it's still relying on obj-c for ios.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena I'm not too familiar with UIKit on obj-c, but the doc states it's an `@property`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also set the scrollview's bounces

like this,It's simple

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        scrollView.bounces = NO;
    }else{
        scrollView.bounces = YES;
    }
}
```