# How to disable bouncing effect in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am running a `WkWebView` which is rendering my web content in my app. However when I am scrolling at the top/bottom of the page (vertically) the page bounces like a normal web page and I am losing the native User experience.

I have done some research on this topic which apperantly is a pretty common issue But non of the answeres resolved my problem.

What most people suggest is to use the following: `wkWebView.scrollView.bounces = false`. But for some reason it has no affect in my webView at all.

Help anyone?

i.e. I prefer solving the issue with native swift rather then injecting js etc..

Comment: Have you tried setting to offset as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407633/how-to-stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically-scrolling-bottom

Comment: @DocForNoc I try'd it but didn't work. I also noticed something wierd for some reason the `scrollViewDidScroll` doesn't get called at all. despite the fact that I set `wkWebView.scrollView.delegate = self`

Comment: I guess the problem is somewhere with the web code which is disabling certain scrollview functions. it's clearly not a problem with my swift code.

Comment: Could be. You can load a simple HTML into your WKWebView instance and test if there is any difference and the behaviour and receiving the delegate methods.

Answer (score 24):

This is work for me:

```
wKWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

Comment: Are you serious? OP said *What most people suggest is to use the following: wkWebView.scrollView.bounces = false. But for some reason it has no affect in my webView at all*.

Comment: :) I agree that I wrote the problem before I read it. But Yes, i'm still serious. I needed the same thing. But there was no answer on the first screen that came up with the search result. After I solved my problem, I wrote the code that worked for me. Do not leave an old question unanswered, it will help many people to help those who like me. What's wrong with that? This answer is a response to %99.9 when searched according to the title of the problem.

Comment: If bounces = NO isn't working, it's possible your webview wasn't initialized.  Verify that your webview isn't nil, when you disable bounce.

Comment: What would be the equivalent command in obj-c? I'm using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) and it's still relying on obj-c for ios.

Answer (score 5):

for me, it works when I set these two:

```
webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
webView.scrollView.bounces = false
```

but some H5 still bouncing, I guess it's the situation caused by the website itself.

Comment: What would be the equivalent command in obj-c? I'm using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) and it's still relying on obj-c for ios.

Comment: And did you find a way to prevent the bounce on the website itself?

Answer (score 3):

This may be a problem with where you are doing this. This does not work when executed in the `LoadView` function. This only works if it is run in the `ViewDidLoad` function.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mainWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
        ...
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent command in obj-c? I'm using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/) and it's still relying on obj-c for ios.

Comment: @UcheOzoemena https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500761/stop-uiwebview-from-bouncing-vertically

Comment: @UcheOzoemena The link above will give you a solution.